# How to get gnome-terminal in English?

Tags: gnome, locale, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to select a different language for a specific application? On some systems I run Fedora15/Gnome in German, but want to use the Terminal in English including for the simple prompt questions like: Y/N instead of j/N = Ja/Nein etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can launch any program with a different language by setting the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable (or `LANG` to include other regional settings besides display language such as sort order, number and date formatting, etc).

```
$ LANG=en_US gnome-terminal
```

Keep in mind that anything you launch FROM that terminal will inherit the language. If you specifically want a program to run with your you could start it up with:

```
$ LANG=de_DE program_to_run_in_german
```

Comment: thank you Caleb ! how can I add this command to the gnome shortcut in the menu bar ?

Comment: I suggest you right click on the gnome-terminal menu item and "add to panel" to get a copy of it put in your panel as a launcher. Then right click on it and edit it's properties so that it runs the command and shown above. Basically change `gnome-terminal` to `LANG=en_US gnome-terminal`.

Comment: I don't know about other DE but gnome fails with this command line. Something like `bash -c "LANG=en_US.utf8 gnome-terminal"` works. If you want to change the menu entry, you can copy the `gnome-terminal.desktop` to `${XDG_DATA_HOME:-~/.local/share}/applications` and modify it.

Comment: @msec Specifically, for messages, you should set `LC_MESSAGES` rather than `LANG` (which has other implications).